# What's the name of this device from Doraemon?

Tags: doraemon

[image]

What's the name of the device in this image that looks like a hen? It's from the movie *Doraemon: Nobita's New Great Adventure in the Underworld*.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please include an actual image of the object you are asking about; this clip looks suspect, and unless you improve this question it is likely to be closed.

Comment: Sorry i can't find the image in Google i have only seen in one movie and in only anime episode

Comment: Do you know which anime episode? It's not listed as a gadget used in the movie on the wiki: https://doraemon.fandom.com/wiki/Doraemon:_Nobita%27s_New_Great_Adventure_into_the_Underworld_~The_7_Magic_Users~#Gadgets_used

Comment: Sorry this gadget is not used in this movie but shown inside doraemon pocket

Comment: Unexpectedly i also found a gadget similar to this it is called snacks chicken which looks like chicken but used to create foods i found it but can't find in wiki only in anime it found to between 2000 to 2012